# Git remove push issue with post-receive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, push, vps

I've setup my vps with this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps)

but when I push from my local repository to the remote i get this error:

```
... sending is complete but...
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1316/1316), done.
remote: /bin/sh: 0: Can't open git —work-tree=/var/www/my_website.com/html --git-dir=/var/repo/my_website.git checkout -f
To ssh://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/var/repo/my_website.git
* [new branch]      master -> master
```

I've set: chmod -R 777 /var/repo/my_website.git
along with chmod +x post-receive

Is there an issue with the permissions of the /var/www/my_website.com/html ?
How do i solve this? Im trying to push a rails 6 project

Comment: Your `git —work-tree=/var/w...` line has some suspect character(s): e.g., the `-` here is not a hyphen but rather an en-dash (and it should be two hyphens anyway). Perhaps the space is a non-breaking space. Make sure your post-receive script actually works, by running it yourself on the server. Note that `git checkout -f` like this (with the `--work-tree` etc) is a really awfully crap-tastic way to do deployment. It *can* work, but it's not a substitute for a real deployment system.

Comment: checked it out... its double en-dashes so i suppose its correct on that part. i did your suggestion, i ran the whole line with a sudo on the ssh remote terminal and it worked.
So what's wrong with the post-receive ?

Comment: It should be hyphens (ASCII 45, U+002D), not en-dashes (no ASCII value, U+2013) or em-dashes (U+2014). But if it works OK from the command line, it should work as run by `sh`; that `sh: 0:` error should not be happening.

Comment: i entered this line:
`#!/bin/sh git --work-tree=/var/www/my_website.com/html --git-dir=/var/repo/my_website.git checkout -f`

is it safe to insert sudo before git --work-tree... :

..sh sudo git --work...

Comment: That should be *two* lines: `#! /bin/sh` as the first line (with newline only, no carriage return, at the end), and then `git --work-tree...` as the second line. It's not generally wise to run this as the super-user though: set things up so that the *Git* user has the appropriate privilege, or create a separate "deploy" user or use a real deployment system.

Comment: i took a different approach.
I created a deploy user with sudo privileges.
Changed the location of my rails app to /home/deploy/my_app/public
and also updated the server block of nginx to point to that path.
Plus changed locally the git remote add to login as deploy user just in case there was somewhere a chmod issue with the previous approach.
But im having the same issue.
I can only make it work with the checkout -f command in the remote terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`git push -f origin master`

I hope this will forcefully push all the changes from the local repository to the GitHub repository.